# Find the docker containers using an image?

Tags: docker

If I have the ID of an image how can I find out which containers are using this image? When removing an image that is still used you get an error message:

```
$ docker rmi 77b0318b76b3
Error response from daemon: Conflict, cannot delete 77b0318b76b3 because the container 21ee2cbc7cec is using it, use -f to force
```

But how could I find this out in an automated way without trying to remove it?

Comment: I was trying something along the lines of:

docker ps | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2;}' | while read image; do docker history $image | awk '{print $1;}'| tail -n +2 ; done | sort| uniq

I thought this would have listed all images referenced by the currently running containers, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: if you want to list the images  of the active containers `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Image}}' $(docker ps -q)` and for all the containers `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Image}}' $(docker ps -qa)`

Answer (score 7):

This will list all containers using your $IMAGE_ID.

**$IMAGE_ID** can be `77b0318b76b3` or `namespace/repo:tag`.

**E.g.:** $IMAGE_ID="77b0318b76b3"

```
docker container ls --all --filter=ancestor=$IMAGE_ID --format "{{.ID}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
docker ps -a | grep `docker images | grep IMAGE_ID | awk '{print $1":"$2}'` | awk '{print $1}'
```

- With *docker ps -a* you get the list of all the containers including
  the ones you are interested in.
- The problem is that you have the IMAGE NAME there but you need the IMAGE ID.
- You can use *docker images* to get the IMAGE ID for a given IMAGE NAME and that is what you use
  in your grep to filter by your IMAGE ID.
- Finally you get the first column to show only the CONTAINER IDs.

Example:

```
docker ps -a \
 | grep `docker images | grep 3a041c1b0a05 | awk '{print $1":"$2}'` \
 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
4d6fb8a7149f
2baa726b1aa5
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

f you want to list the images of the active containers `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Image}}' $(docker ps -q)` and for all the containers `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Image}}' $(docker ps -qa)`

Comment: If the image has a nice name it will just output the name of the image, not the ID.

Comment: So let's print the Image name and the ID `docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Image}} {{ .State.Pid}}' $(docker ps -q)` Is that what you want?